# Map count really counts or just checks existence

Tags: c++, stl

In CPP primer or other websites I have found the language of `count` (from `map` STL) definition very vague and misleading:

> Searches the container for elements with a key equivalent to k and returns the number of matches

Now what I have studied so far is that `key` is singular and so is the mapped value - the mapped value can be changed through assignment.

So doesn't it just returns whether the container contains the key or not? Rather than the *count*? Where am I wrong in understanding the concept?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count - "Return value
Number of elements with key that compares equivalent to key or x, which is either 1 or 0 for (1)."

Comment: probably exists to aid generic programming

Comment: it seems pretty clear to me, it there is one element with that key it returns 1, if there are no elements with that key it returns 0. Note that 0 is equivalent to false and 1 to true, so you can use the result of count() like a bool if that's what you want. The reason count returns an int and not a bool is because other containers do allow duplicate keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `std::map`'s `count`() will always return either 0 or 1.

But the C++ library has other associative containers that might very well have multiple values for the same key. Like `std::multimap` and `std::multiset`. And by a very lucky coincidence they also have a `count()` method that may actually return values greater than 1.

But what this allows you to do is metaprogramming by developing templates that can use any associative container, one that may or may not be unique. All your template needs to do is use `count()` to determine how many values exist in the container with the given key, and the end result can be used with either `std::map` or `std::multimap`. It won't care in the slightest. In both cases, your template will get the right answer: the number of values in the container with the given key.

Comment: You meant generic programming? I am not sure how metaprogramming is relevant

Answer (score 1):

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/)

> Because all elements in a map container are unique, the function can only return 1 (if the element is found) or zero (otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

While the previous answers are correct when it comes to the `count` overload, that takes an argument of type `std::map::key_type`, they don't address the other overload that takes a templated key:

```cpp
template< class K > 
size_type count( const K& x ) const;
```

As is explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count), this overload "returns the number of elements with key that compares equivalent to the value x." This can return a value higher than 1 by using a custom comparator that defines comparisons with a custom type.

In the example below, I write a comparator that defines comparisons for the struct `StartsWithK`. This allows me to pass an instance of the struct as a key.

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// Type for key argument
struct StartsWithK {};

// Custom comparator
struct Comp{
  using is_transparent = void;
  bool operator()(std::string lhs, std::string rhs) const {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) < 0;
  }
  bool operator()(std::string lhs, StartsWithK rhs) const {
    return tolower(lhs[0]) < 'k';
  }
  bool operator()(StartsWithK lhs, std::string rhs) const {
    return 'k' < tolower(rhs[0]);
  }
};

int main() {
  // Pass custom comparator as template argument
  typedef std::map<std::string,bool,Comp> IntMap;
  IntMap map;

  // Some dummy entries, note that there are four keys that start with k
  map.emplace("army",true);
  map.emplace("knight",true);
  map.emplace("key",true);
  map.emplace("kilogram",true);
  map.emplace("robot",true);
  map.emplace("karma",true);
  map.emplace("sale",true);

  // Display the results of std::map::equal_range and std::map::count
  IntMap::const_iterator it1;
  IntMap::const_iterator it2;
  std::tie(it1,it2) = map.equal_range(StartsWithK());
  std::cout << it1->first << " " << it2->first << std::endl;

  std::cout << map.count(StartsWithK()) << std::endl;
}
```

The console output is:

```
karma robot
4
```

I have played around with this and what I found is the following:

1. The matching keys must follow each other directly in `std::map`'s key order
2. The keys preceding the matching keys must compare lower than the matching keys
3. The key's following the matching keys must compare greater than the matching keys

In other words, the above example works because all keys that start with the letter k are already in order, since `std::map` orders its keys alphabetically. Conversely I tried implementing a map with `int` keys, using `count` to find the number of even keys, but that didn't work because odd and even numbers alternate.

My guess of what happens behind the scenes is that `std::map` internally runs `lower_bound(key)` and `upper_bound(key)` and then returns the distance between the return iterators as result. From my testing I can tell that `count` does not check each key individually for equivalence.

I haven't found any example online for this use of a custom comparator and the documentation is sparse and possibly wrong.